# Using the power iteration method to compute the largest eigen value for hermitian matrix

Tags: matrices

I have read a published paper that does the following:

Starts with $\bf G$ being a Hermitian matrix

The authors then used the power iteration over G to find the largest eigen value as follows: assume u is an all ones vector then

for  $1 \leq s \leq S$

$z= G \,u $

$m = arg max \,|z_i|$

$u = z/m$

end

where the second step in this for loop is supposed to extract the element in $z$ that has the largest amplitude. The largest eigen value is then $m$.

I tried to implement this in MATLAB, the problem I encounter is that $m$ is complex which should not be the case. In my simulation I basically wrote

```
for s=1:5
z= G*u
m= max(z)
u = z/m
end
```

Why is my eigen value complex?

Comment: You did not take the modulus of each entry.

Comment: Thanks, do you mean I should take the magnitude and that would be the square root of the (imaginary  part squared + real part squared )?@Ian

Comment: that isn't the power iteration. Please cf the Wikipedia. Also, I don't see that this iteration would produce an useful approximation.

Comment: can you please guide me to which step is missing in particular?

Comment: $z$ is okay. but the approximation to the largest eigenvalue **in modulus** is given by $m=u^H z/(u^H u)$. **After that, replace $u$ by $z$!**

Comment: @Ian should iI replace max(z) by norm 2 of $z$ instead, thanks?